# Setting a name (alias) for codeigniter's email recipient

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

In the [user manual of Codeigniter's Email Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html), under **Email Function Reference**, wer see `$this->email->from()` with two parameters: an email address as well as as `'Your Name'` that is set as the second parameter.

But when it comes to `$this->email->to()`, we cannot set the recipient's name. While we can see that in the real world (eg. gmail), the request has been answered as it's expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't waste your time trying to pass recipient's name with code like this:

```
 $this->email->to('John Smith <john@example.com>');
```

because *to()* function clean all parameters passed with clean_email()

```
    public function to($to)
    {
        $to = $this->_str_to_array($to);
        $to = $this->clean_email($to);
    // ...



/**
 * Clean Extended Email Address: Joe Smith <joe@smith.com>
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
public function clean_email($email)
{
    if ( ! is_array($email))
    {
        if (preg_match('/\<(.*)\>/', $email, $match))
        {
            return $match['1'];
        }
        else
        {
            return $email;
        }
    }
    // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, function `to()` does not provide any means of settings recipient's name.

However, you could extend the `Email` class and add manually that additional functionality such as setting names.

Otherwise you should probably use another tool for sending emails. For example `PHPMailer`.

Comment: `+1` Thank you very much, and sorry that no two answers can be marked as accepted. Anyway I respect your time and answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a trick to bypass the cleaning process in Codeigniter.
Instead of using `$this->email->to()`, you should manually set the email header.

```
$this->email->set_header('To', '"' . $recipient_display_name . '" <'. $recipient_email . '>');
```

I haven't tested out providing a list of recipient emails, but I think the idea is the same.